# deeplearning4j dependencies error

Tags: java, scala, dependencies, deep-learning

I am trying to run the examples available at `https://github.com/kogecoo/dl4j-0.4-examples-scala`

If I try to compile with sbt in the terminal or if I import it as an sbt project in intellij I get the following error:

```
lucas-MacBook-Pro:dl4j-0.4-examples-scala donbeo$ sbt
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/donbeo/Documents/dl4j-0.4-examples-scala/project
[info] Set current project to deeplearning4j-examples-scala (in build file:/Users/donbeo/Documents/dl4j-0.4-examples-scala/)
> console
[info] Updating {file:/Users/donbeo/Documents/dl4j-0.4-examples-scala/}root...
[info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.4 ...
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom
[warn]  module not found: commons-io#commons-io;2.4
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/local/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype OSS Snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype release Repository: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom
[warn] ==== Local Maven Repository: tried
[warn]   file:///Users/donbeo/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom
[info] Resolving com.google.guava#guava;18.0 ...
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.pom
[warn]  module not found: com.google.guava#guava;18.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/local/com.google.guava/guava/18.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype OSS Snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype release Repository: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.pom
[warn] ==== Local Maven Repository: tried
[warn]   file:///Users/donbeo/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.pom
[info] Resolving org.deeplearning4j#deeplearning4j-core;0.4-rc3.4 ...
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-core/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-core-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-core/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-core-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-core/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-core-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-core/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-core-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[warn]  module not found: org.deeplearning4j#deeplearning4j-core;0.4-rc3.4
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/local/org.deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-core/0.4-rc3.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-core/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-core-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-core/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-core-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype OSS Snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-core/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-core-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype release Repository: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-core/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-core-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[warn] ==== Local Maven Repository: tried
[warn]   file:///Users/donbeo/.m2/repository/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-core/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-core-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[info] Resolving org.deeplearning4j#deeplearning4j-nlp;0.4-rc3.4 ...
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-nlp/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-nlp-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-nlp/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-nlp-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-nlp/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-nlp-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-nlp/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-nlp-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[warn]  module not found: org.deeplearning4j#deeplearning4j-nlp;0.4-rc3.4
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/local/org.deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-nlp/0.4-rc3.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-nlp/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-nlp-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-nlp/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-nlp-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype OSS Snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-nlp/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-nlp-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype release Repository: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-nlp/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-nlp-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[warn] ==== Local Maven Repository: tried
[warn]   file:///Users/donbeo/.m2/repository/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-nlp/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-nlp-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[info] Resolving org.deeplearning4j#deeplearning4j-ui;0.4-rc3.4 ...
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-ui/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-ui-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-ui/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-ui-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-ui/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-ui-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-ui/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-ui-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[warn]  module not found: org.deeplearning4j#deeplearning4j-ui;0.4-rc3.4
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/local/org.deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-ui/0.4-rc3.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-ui/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-ui-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-ui/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-ui-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype OSS Snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-ui/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-ui-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype release Repository: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-ui/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-ui-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[warn] ==== Local Maven Repository: tried
[warn]   file:///Users/donbeo/.m2/repository/org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-ui/0.4-rc3.4/deeplearning4j-ui-0.4-rc3.4.pom
[info] Resolving org.jblas#jblas;1.2.4 ...
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jblas/jblas/1.2.4/jblas-1.2.4.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jblas/jblas/1.2.4/jblas-1.2.4.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/jblas/jblas/1.2.4/jblas-1.2.4.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/org/jblas/jblas/1.2.4/jblas-1.2.4.pom
[warn]  module not found: org.jblas#jblas;1.2.4
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/local/org.jblas/jblas/1.2.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jblas/jblas/1.2.4/jblas-1.2.4.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jblas/jblas/1.2.4/jblas-1.2.4.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype OSS Snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/jblas/jblas/1.2.4/jblas-1.2.4.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype release Repository: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/org/jblas/jblas/1.2.4/jblas-1.2.4.pom
[warn] ==== Local Maven Repository: tried
[warn]   file:///Users/donbeo/.m2/repository/org/jblas/jblas/1.2.4/jblas-1.2.4.pom
[info] Resolving org.nd4j#canova-nd4j-image;0.0.0.11 ...
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/nd4j/canova-nd4j-image/0.0.0.11/canova-nd4j-image-0.0.0.11.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/nd4j/canova-nd4j-image/0.0.0.11/canova-nd4j-image-0.0.0.11.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/nd4j/canova-nd4j-image/0.0.0.11/canova-nd4j-image-0.0.0.11.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/org/nd4j/canova-nd4j-image/0.0.0.11/canova-nd4j-image-0.0.0.11.pom
[warn]  module not found: org.nd4j#canova-nd4j-image;0.0.0.11
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/local/org.nd4j/canova-nd4j-image/0.0.0.11/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/nd4j/canova-nd4j-image/0.0.0.11/canova-nd4j-image-0.0.0.11.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/nd4j/canova-nd4j-image/0.0.0.11/canova-nd4j-image-0.0.0.11.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype OSS Snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/nd4j/canova-nd4j-image/0.0.0.11/canova-nd4j-image-0.0.0.11.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype release Repository: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/org/nd4j/canova-nd4j-image/0.0.0.11/canova-nd4j-image-0.0.0.11.pom
[warn] ==== Local Maven Repository: tried
[warn]   file:///Users/donbeo/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/canova-nd4j-image/0.0.0.11/canova-nd4j-image-0.0.0.11.pom
[info] Resolving org.nd4j#nd4j-jblas;0.4-rc3.5 ...
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/nd4j/nd4j-jblas/0.4-rc3.5/nd4j-jblas-0.4-rc3.5.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/nd4j/nd4j-jblas/0.4-rc3.5/nd4j-jblas-0.4-rc3.5.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/nd4j/nd4j-jblas/0.4-rc3.5/nd4j-jblas-0.4-rc3.5.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/org/nd4j/nd4j-jblas/0.4-rc3.5/nd4j-jblas-0.4-rc3.5.pom
[warn]  module not found: org.nd4j#nd4j-jblas;0.4-rc3.5
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/local/org.nd4j/nd4j-jblas/0.4-rc3.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/nd4j/nd4j-jblas/0.4-rc3.5/nd4j-jblas-0.4-rc3.5.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/nd4j/nd4j-jblas/0.4-rc3.5/nd4j-jblas-0.4-rc3.5.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype OSS Snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/nd4j/nd4j-jblas/0.4-rc3.5/nd4j-jblas-0.4-rc3.5.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype release Repository: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/org/nd4j/nd4j-jblas/0.4-rc3.5/nd4j-jblas-0.4-rc3.5.pom
[warn] ==== Local Maven Repository: tried
[warn]   file:///Users/donbeo/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-jblas/0.4-rc3.5/nd4j-jblas-0.4-rc3.5.pom
[info] Resolving org.nd4j#nd4j-x86;0.4-rc3.5 ...
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/nd4j/nd4j-x86/0.4-rc3.5/nd4j-x86-0.4-rc3.5.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/nd4j/nd4j-x86/0.4-rc3.5/nd4j-x86-0.4-rc3.5.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/nd4j/nd4j-x86/0.4-rc3.5/nd4j-x86-0.4-rc3.5.pom
[error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/org/nd4j/nd4j-x86/0.4-rc3.5/nd4j-x86-0.4-rc3.5.pom
[warn]  module not found: org.nd4j#nd4j-x86;0.4-rc3.5
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/local/org.nd4j/nd4j-x86/0.4-rc3.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/nd4j/nd4j-x86/0.4-rc3.5/nd4j-x86-0.4-rc3.5.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/nd4j/nd4j-x86/0.4-rc3.5/nd4j-x86-0.4-rc3.5.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype OSS Snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/nd4j/nd4j-x86/0.4-rc3.5/nd4j-x86-0.4-rc3.5.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype release Repository: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/org/nd4j/nd4j-x86/0.4-rc3.5/nd4j-x86-0.4-rc3.5.pom
[warn] ==== Local Maven Repository: tried
[warn]   file:///Users/donbeo/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-x86/0.4-rc3.5/nd4j-x86-0.4-rc3.5.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: commons-io#commons-io;2.4: not found
[warn]  :: com.google.guava#guava;18.0: not found
[warn]  :: org.deeplearning4j#deeplearning4j-core;0.4-rc3.4: not found
[warn]  :: org.deeplearning4j#deeplearning4j-nlp;0.4-rc3.4: not found
[warn]  :: org.deeplearning4j#deeplearning4j-ui;0.4-rc3.4: not found
[warn]  :: org.jblas#jblas;1.2.4: not found
[warn]  :: org.nd4j#canova-nd4j-image;0.0.0.11: not found
[warn]  :: org.nd4j#nd4j-jblas;0.4-rc3.5: not found
[warn]  :: org.nd4j#nd4j-x86;0.4-rc3.5: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: commons-io#commons-io;2.4: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.google.guava#guava;18.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.deeplearning4j#deeplearning4j-core;0.4-rc3.4: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.deeplearning4j#deeplearning4j-nlp;0.4-rc3.4: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.deeplearning4j#deeplearning4j-ui;0.4-rc3.4: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jblas#jblas;1.2.4: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.nd4j#canova-nd4j-image;0.0.0.11: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.nd4j#nd4j-jblas;0.4-rc3.5: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.nd4j#nd4j-x86;0.4-rc3.5: not found
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Oct 15, 2015 2:20:12 PM
>
```

I am not expert of java/scala so I am probably doing something wrong. 
How can I solve?

Comment: How do you build project?

Comment: [error] Server access Error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused url=https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom
your proxy is problem

Comment: It was actually  a proxy problem. I have solved deactivating the proxy options in prereferences/network,.